# How to get the output of a certain layer in the SLIM vgg16 net?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get the output of the fc6 layer in the slim vgg16 net, is there any good way to do that?

Actually I have figured out one possible solution, please help me confirm its correctness.

The output of the fc6 layer is actually the result of the `Relu` op, i.e., the activation function. And I find the name of it is `vgg_16/fc6/Relu` by executing `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()`. So, maybe the result of `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('vgg_16/fc6/Relu:0')` is what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have extracted from this Tensorflow code for image segmentation ([link](https://github.com/warmspringwinds/tf-image-segmentation/blob/master/tf_image_segmentation/models/fcn_8s.py)) this is how you can extract the output at one layer of a predefined TF-Slim model:

```
    from tensorflow.contrib.slim import nets

    last_layer_logits, end_points = nets.vgg.vgg_16(img_batch, num_classes=num_classes)

    # examples
    pool4_features = end_points['vgg_16/pool4']
    fc8_features = end_points['vgg_16/fc8']
```

If you are using another argscope on top of the actual vgg_16 model, you should add it before the vgg_16 argscope:

```
    fc8_features = end_points['my_great_model_argscope/' + 'vgg_16/fc8']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Your method does work and so does mine. I didn't know the usage of `end_points` in TF-Slim model, and the doc on GitHub doesn't mention a single word about it at all!

Comment: After playing around for a while with Tensorflow, I have found that TF-Slim is the best solution for me, but yes, lacks a lot of documentation. I have learned a lot from following this IPython notebook (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb) included in tensorflow/models repository. Good luck with your quest!